# using microsoft-cognitive thumbnail generation return unusable file with photos from Android phone

Tags: android, azure, azure-cognitive-services

Can't find any direct reference to the problem online.  I've created an Azure function to create thumbnails using the cognitive services tool (following the guide at https://www.hackster.io/achindra/azure-function-apps-running-custom-code-on-blob-insertion-d71aba and only modifying it to use the EASTUS location instead of projectoxford).  All works find and dandy, but I have found that whilst all thumbnails come back marked application/octet-stream (all originals are image/jpeg), only those that were taken on any of: DSLR, Windows Phone, iOS device are usable and work both as images on a website or in photos app on the computer.  However all photos taken with an Android phone (well, all the ones I have tested so far!) come back with a file format that is not supported.  They are .jpg, and have content type of application/octet-stream as do the other thumbnails. Any bright ideas gratefully received.

Comment: Are you able to include a link to one of the original images?
Note that the API does not accept input images larger than 4MB, which, depending on your camera DPI, you might be exceeding.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn’t spotted that limit in the documentation. I’d swear some of the working ones are bigger than 4MB, but will check in the office tomorrow. The droid ones will be bigger than that, so I may have to think again on the project.

Comment: Another thing to know that image classifiers often scale images down to a smaller size before evaluating the image data.  In other words, sending a higher-resolution doesn't necessarily result in higher accuracy.  You might scale down the image on the phone and save on network (and therefore battery) load.

Comment: thanks, I downscaled on the phone and it converted OK, so it seems that sometimes the API will accept bigger files and process.  (assuming of course the native scaling didn't tweak the spec of the file at all).  The on-profit project is for site where independent volunteers will be uploading images, so I won't be able to prevent them attempting (and succeeding) to upload images larger than the thumbnail API will handle.

Comment: i went ahead and repeated the comment in the form of an answer so future readers can get it without wading through the comments.  Go ahead and accept the answer if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Cognitive Vision APIs do not accept images larger than 4MB.  It will return a InvalidImageSize error when you do.

The general advice is to downscale the image on the client before posting it to the API if your images are larger.

Comment: except, it didn't throw that or any other error, it worked successfully, just delivered a bad thumbnail.

Comment: got original and output here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtWT2TFd-QD1neQOdIlWzUVs1hGTXw ; 'scuse delay-this is a non-work side project.

Comment: You should be getting HTTP 400 Bad Request response.  The body of the response in this case is JSON (the response header correctly reflects this) with the content `{"code":"InvalidImageSize","requestId":"dcd73d67-676a-489f-87f7-e18e4c8e117f","message":"Input image is too large."}`